# Problems of checking elements in container (c++, visual studio 2017)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, visualizer

I want to check the elements in container. 
Like this:

[image: Show elements]

But now it shows like this:

[image: Show address?]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also take the [tour] and read [ask] and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly don't forget how to create a [mcve] to show us in the question itself.

Comment: There might be the necessary visualizer missing. [Create custom views of data in the Visual Studio debugger (C#, Visual Basic, C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/viewing-data-in-the-debugger?view=vs-2017) Concerning Qt, there probably are ready visualizers available (which have to be copied into the resp. dirctory in case). For your own data types, you may write a [custom visualizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-visualizers-of-data?view=vs-2017). (We did, and they work well.) ;-)

Comment: Found a qt visualizer in github. Thx Scheff!